# Is there a fast estimation of simple regression (a regression line with only intercept and slope)?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

This question relates to a machine learning feature selection procedure.

I have a large matrix of features - columns are the features of the subjects (rows):

```
set.seed(1)
features.mat <- matrix(rnorm(10*100),ncol=100)
colnames(features.mat) <- paste("F",1:100,sep="")
rownames(features.mat) <- paste("S",1:10,sep="")
```

The response was measured for each subject (`S`) under different conditions (`C`) and therefore looks like this:

```
response.df <-
data.frame(S = c(sapply(1:10, function(x) rep(paste("S", x, sep = ""),100))),
           C = rep(paste("C", 1:100, sep = ""), 10),
           response = rnorm(1000), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

So I match the subjects in `response.df`:

```
match.idx <- match(response.df$S, rownames(features.mat))
```

I'm looking for a fast way to compute the univariate regression of each feature and the response.

Anything faster than this?:

```
fun <- function(f){
  fit <- lm(response.df$response ~ features.mat[match.idx,f])
  beta <- coef(summary(fit))
  data.frame(feature = colnames(features.mat)[f], effect = beta[2,1],
             p.val = beta[2,4], stringsAsFactors = F))
  }

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:ncol(features.mat), fun))
```

I am interested in marginal boost, i.e., methods other than using parallel computing via `mclapply` or `mclapply2`.

Comment: try `lm.fit` (or even `.lm.fit`)

Comment: That's right only Estimate and Pr(>|t|)

Comment: Zheyuan Li it seems that lm.chol will be fitting an lm to all features in one model whereas I'm looking for a fast way to fit an lm to each feature,target pair separately. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yep, my actual data is millions of features

Comment: `speedlm.fit` from the `speedglm` package may be useful if you have a lot of observations.  It's pretty fast when you have millions of observations, and it returns a pretty rich object.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi On my quick benchmarks with your toy data, changing from 50 observations to 1e6 then 5e6 and then 1e7 observations, `speedlm.fit` was a bit (~25%) faster whether I used eigen, Cholesky, or qr as the method.  Anyway, I meant it to be a helpful comment for OP and/or future readers (whose goals may not be exactly the same).

Comment: @ZheyuanLi `speedlm.fit` barely (~5%) faster in the case of 1e6, ~8% for 5e6, and ~25% faster for 1e7 (based on median time).  I'm not sure what BLAS I'm using on this particular machine, but I have to head out for the evening.

Answer (score 9):

I would provide a light-weighed toy routine for estimation of a simple regression model: `y ~ x`, i.e., a regression line with only an intercept and slope. **As will be seen, this is 36 times faster than `lm` + `summary.lm`.**

```
## toy data
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(50)
y <- 0.3 * x + 0.1 + rnorm(50, sd = 0.05)

## fast estimation of simple linear regression: y ~ x 
simplelm <- function (x, y) {
  ## number of data
  n <- length(x)
  ## centring
  y0 <- sum(y) / length(y); yc <- y - y0
  x0 <- sum(x) / length(x); xc <- x - x0
  ## fitting an intercept-free model: yc ~ xc + 0
  xty <- c(crossprod(xc, yc))
  xtx <- c(crossprod(xc))
  slope <- xty / xtx
  rc <- yc - xc * slope
  ## Pearson estimate of residual standard error
  sigma2 <- c(crossprod(rc)) / (n - 2)
  ## standard error for slope
  slope_se <- sqrt(sigma2 / xtx)
  ## t-score and p-value for slope
  tscore <- slope / slope_se
  pvalue <- 2 * pt(abs(tscore), n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ## return estimation summary for slope
  c("Estimate" = slope, "Std. Error" = slope_se, "t value" = tscore, "Pr(>|t|)" = pvalue)
  }
```

Let's have a test:

```
simplelm(x, y)

#    Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|) 
#2.656737e-01 2.279663e-02 1.165408e+01 1.337380e-15
```

On the other hand, `lm` + `summary.lm` gives:

```
coef(summary(lm(y ~ x)))

#             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 0.1154549 0.01373051  8.408633 5.350248e-11
#x           0.2656737 0.02279663 11.654079 1.337380e-15
```

So the result matches. If you require R-squared and adjusted R-squared, it can be easily computed, too.

---

Let's have a benchmark:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(10000)
y <- 0.3 * x + 0.1 + rnorm(10000, sd = 0.05)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(coef(summary(lm(y ~ x))), simplelm(x, y))

#Unit: microseconds
#                     expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq
# coef(summary(lm(y ~ x))) 14158.28 14305.28 17545.1544 14444.34 17089.00
#           simplelm(x, y)   235.08   265.72   485.4076   288.20   319.46
#      max neval cld
# 114662.2   100   b
#   3409.6   100  a
```

**Holy!!! We have 36 times boost!**

---

## Remark-1 (solving normal equation)

The `simplelm` is based on solving normal equation via Cholesky factorization. But since it is simple, no actual matrix computation is involved. If we need regression with multiple covariates, we can use the [`lm.chol` defined in my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604244/4891738).

Normal equation can also be solved by using LU factorization. I will not touch on this, but if you feel interested, here is it: [Solving normal equation gives different coefficients from using `lm`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113715/4891738).

## Remark-2 (alternative via `cor.test`)

The `simplelm` is an extension to the `fastsim` in my answer [Monte Carlo simulation of correlation between two Brownian motion (continuous random walk)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944448/4891738). An alternative way is based on `cor.test`. It is also much faster than `lm` + `summary.lm`, but as shown in that answer, it is yet slower than my proposal above.

## Remark-3 (alternative via QR method)

QR based method is also possible, in which case we want to use `.lm.fit`, a light-weighed wrapper for `qr.default`, `qr.coef`, `qr.fitted` and `qr.resid` at C-level. Here is how we can add this option to our `simplelm`:

```
## fast estimation of simple linear regression: y ~ x 
simplelm <- function (x, y, QR = FALSE) {
  ## number of data
  n <- length(x)
  ## centring
  y0 <- sum(y) / length(y); yc <- y - y0
  x0 <- sum(x) / length(x); xc <- x - x0
  ## fitting intercept free model: yc ~ xc + 0
  if (QR) {
    fit <- .lm.fit(matrix(xc), yc)
    slope <- fit$coefficients
    rc <- fit$residuals
    } else {
    xty <- c(crossprod(xc, yc))
    xtx <- c(crossprod(xc))
    slope <- xty / xtx
    rc <- yc - xc * slope
    }
  ## Pearson estimate of residual standard error
  sigma2 <- c(crossprod(rc)) / (n - 2)
  ## standard error for slope
  if (QR) {
    slope_se <- sqrt(sigma2) / abs(fit$qr[1])
    } else {
    slope_se <- sqrt(sigma2 / xtx)
    }
  ## t-score and p-value for slope
  tscore <- slope / slope_se
  pvalue <- 2 * pt(abs(tscore), n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ## return estimation summary for slope
  c("Estimate" = slope, "Std. Error" = slope_se, "t value" = tscore, "Pr(>|t|)" = pvalue)
  }
```

For our toy data, both QR method and Cholesky method give the same result:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(50)
y <- 0.3 * x + 0.1 + rnorm(50, sd = 0.05)

simplelm(x, y, TRUE)

#    Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|) 
#2.656737e-01 2.279663e-02 1.165408e+01 1.337380e-15 

simplelm(x, y, FALSE)

#    Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|) 
#2.656737e-01 2.279663e-02 1.165408e+01 1.337380e-15
```

QR methods is known to be 2 ~ 3 times slower than Cholesky method (Read my answer [Why the built-in lm function is so slow in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37919817/4891738) for detailed explanation). Here is a quick check:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(10000)
y <- 0.3 * x + 0.1 + rnorm(10000, sd = 0.05)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(simplelm(x, y, TRUE), simplelm(x, y))

#Unit: microseconds
#                 expr    min     lq      mean median     uq     max neval cld
# simplelm(x, y, TRUE) 776.88 873.26 1073.1944 908.72 933.82 3420.92   100   b
#       simplelm(x, y) 238.32 292.02  441.9292 310.44 319.32 3515.08   100  a
```

So indeed, `908 / 310 = 2.93`.

## Remark-4 (simple regression for GLM)

If we move on to GLM, there is also a fast, light-weighed version based on `glm.fit`. You can read my answer [R loop help: leave out one observation and run glm one variable at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39947368/4891738) and use function `f` defined there. At the moment `f` is customized to logistic regression, but we can generalize it to other response easily.